# Start google map direction intent with mode

Tags: android, android-intent

How to start android google map direction intent with source and destination latitude and longitude?
And also with traveling mode like bicycle, car...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put navigation mode as **dirflg.**

- `d`  for driving.
- `b`  for bicycle.
- `w`  for walking.
- `l`  for two wheeler.

  ```
  val uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=33.489954,73.098888 &daddr=33.499009,73.101076 &dirflg=w")
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
  intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
  startActivity(intent)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

By direction intent, I am assuming you mean the **Turn By Turn Navigation** intent. To do that you can do the following:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=37.7749,-122.4194&mode=b");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

The main thing here is the `Uri` that is being used. The `&mode=b`at the end of the uri defines bicycling mode. You can also use `d` for driving mode (which is also the default). `w` is for walking.

You can use `q=a+street+address` format, which is demonstrated above or you can also use Latitude and Longitude there in format: `q=latitude,longitude`

Read more about this here: [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)

Comment: thank you for your response .I want to give source lat lng not current location

Comment: @MuhammadImtiaz I have edited the answer, please have a look

Comment: no your answer open google map with current location as source ,but I want to open with my given source location and dest location

Comment: @MuhammadImtiaz, did you put `"google.navigation:q=37.7749,-122.4194&mode=b"` in the uri, it clearly says navigation, which is for Turn By Turn Navigation. The source will be the current device location and the destination will be the destination indicated by the lat long

Comment: I take it that your app is working. Do consider accepting my answer as the solution. :)

Comment: Is there a way to open the map on the state where it shows the directions but turn to turn navigation has not yet started

Comment: I dont think there is an option for your specific use case, but you can open a search view with the lat long of your choice using `geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom` and the user can then start the directions view. Please let everyone know if you find a solution to your specific use case. :)